# Unable to resolve DNS names that are mentioned in the /etc/hosts file

Tags: hosts

I am running RHEL8 and running into a very weird issue. I have host entries in my `/etc/hosts` file, but when I go to ping them, I am getting name resolution errors.

Here's an example of my `/etc/hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
192.168.1.1 myserver.local
```

However, when I go to ping `myserver.local`:

```
# ping myserver.local
connect: Network is unreachable
```

That error message is actually different than others which aren't actual DNS names, such as:

```
# ping krjthekjhterjhterjerjkhterjh.com
ping: krjthekjhterjhterjerjkhterjh.com: No address associated with hostname
You have new mail in /var/spool/mail/root
```

I'm not quite sure why it's specifically saying `connect: Network is unreachable`.

Comment: run `ifconfig`. It will show all network interfaces on the machine. One of it should have `inet 192.168.1.1` in the description. If found - check the network for this interface, if not found - start searching why.

Comment: That's not a name resolution error.  That's your machine telling you it doesn't know how to reach the network on which 192.1681.1 exists.

Comment: It looks like setting a default gateway resolved this issue, which is very interesting.

Comment: @user3447014 That's not surprising. With a default gateway set, your computer is sending the packets to the default gateway, so if an error occurs it'll happen on the router (or past it) and your computer may or may not get an error report back. A better question is: why do you expect 192.168.1.1 to be reachable from your computer?